# Applying Analyzer while using More Like This (mlt) in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to modify the default analyzer for a [More Like This](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html) query in ElasticSearch, so as to ignore stop words (preferably without defining them). To try this out, I constructed a query using the `explain` functionality and what I hope is the [stop analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/analysis-stop-analyzer.html) (`Stop`) as follows,

```
{"search":{"size":1, "fields":["our_id"],"explain":true,"query":{
"mlt":{"analyzer": "Stop", "docs":[{"_id":"99999999"}],
"fields":["text_for_matching"]}} }}
```

However, MLT doesn't seem to parse my analyzer (as I can use anything I like and get no error or change), and as such I see that the stop words are still included in the similarity calculation according to `explain`, `"description": "weight(text_for_matching:the in 4961) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:", "value": 0.013,`

How do I parameterize MLT with an analyzer properly, and will it then ignore stop words in my searches? Or do I need to change the initial indexing to get the behavior I want?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you would need to use the [like](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/query-dsl-mlt-query.html) option with `per_field_analyzer` :

```
{
   "size": 1,
   "fields": [
      "our_id"
   ],
   "explain": true,
   "query": {
      "mlt": {
         "like": [
            {
               "_type": "test",
               "_id": 99999999,
               "per_field_analyzer": {
                  "text_for_matching": "stop"
               }
            }
         ],
         "fields": [
            "text_for_matching"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: For the older ElasticSearch version (1.7) I was using `like` can be replaced with `docs`, and the above will work. Thanks!